# Subscript not working with string formatting mini-language

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend, subscript, legend-properties

Using `matplotlib.plot`'s label argument for [legend entries](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.legend.html) I am trying to implement dynamically generated plot labels with subscripts.

However, when using Python's string formatting mini-language (see [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec) for further info) instead of the old-fashioned `%`-based notation to insert variables to the label strings I am getting different/faulty output. When using `.format()` to insert variables only the first char of the inserted string is a subscript, the others are not. However, as the complete string should be subscript, this is not desired.

Compare legend entry for orange plot with green and blue one:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


sample_string = 'XY'

# writing contents of `sample_string` directly to label raw string results in desired label
label1 = r"$w_{XY} = 20 \frac{{kg_{XY}}}{{kg_{{xyz}}}}$"
plt.plot(0, 0, 'o', label=label1)

# passing contents by using string format mini-language results in faulty label
label2 = r"$w_{0} = 20 \frac{{kg_{0}}}{{kg_{{xyz}}}}$".format(sample_string)
plt.plot(0, 0.5, 'o', label=label2)

# using old-fashioned %-notation to insert string results in desired label
label3 = r"$w_{%s} = 20 \frac{{kg_{%s}}}{{kg_{{xyz}}}}$" % (sample_string, sample_string)
plt.plot(0, 1, 'o', label=label3)

plt.legend(loc='upper center', bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, -0.075), ncol=4)
plt.show()
```

[image: sample diagram]

How can I achieve the same output for both `.format()` and the `%`-notation (compare subscripts in the legend entries of the orange data point with the other two)?

Comment: What exactly is wrong with the output you get?

Comment: Have a look at the legend entry for the orange data. The subscript should look like those in the legend entries for green and blue.

Comment: You're missing one or several `{}` pairs. Check by printing the formatted `label`.